# Where can I find a list of cities with public bicycles available in Europe?

Tags: public-transport, europe, online-resources, planning, bicycles

Whenever I visit a city I find traveling by bicycle very convenient. It's very flexible and you get to see the city in a very friendly way.

I was wondering if there is a website or other resource that lists cities in Europe where public bikes are accessible also to tourists.

Note: I am not referring to companies *renting* bikes. I am really referring to public systems like exist in Paris or Copenhagen where everyone can use bikes.
If the list contains the requirements to use the bicycles that would be a big plus. Eg.: In Paris, if I remember right, you need a Credit Card.

[image: Bicycles in Paris]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Wikipedia is your friend with an entry on [Bicycle sharing systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems).

Comment: If you are looking for a more complete list, that article also includes a link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_bicycle-sharing_systems but even that is probably not complete.  I just added two cities that I knew of.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe not exactly what you're looking for, but [fluctuo](https://fluctuo.com/)<sup>not affiliated</sup> is a shared<sup>1</sup> mobility aggregator that provides a [map](https://multicycles.org/?l=48.84712351154341&l=2.3710298538208012) where it lists all available shared<sup>1</sup> vehicles (bikes, scooters, mopeds) on a location.

Additionally, there is [a Github repository](https://github.com/NABSA/gbfs) that [lists](https://github.com/NABSA/gbfs/blob/master/systems.csv) bike sharing systems that publish their information in accordance with the General Bikeshare Feed Specification (GBFS), which is a standardized data feed for shared mobility system availability.

<sup>1: It's actually all rental mobility, as one always has to pay for the service of using a vehicle. It's just that the vehicle is not rented out at a single location but on different locations in an area.

Clever marketing has spread the term "shared mobility" to give it a friendly and less profit oriented vibe.</sup>